# Is there a way to see all Admob ads in my app

Tags: android, google-play, admob, ads

I have an issue with this Admob ads. I don't want to show a specific group of ads that only I can filter, for that I need to see each and every ad that will go on my app or is already displayed.. Is that possible in any way?
If not, is it possible to see **clicked** ads in my app?

This is really important to me. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can Do it from admob console

go to Moneterization on top-->select your project on left click allow&Block ads and choose what type of ads you want to display

[image: see this]

Comment: I already done all that.. even in Ad Review Center you can't see all ads that show up in your app.. I want to see all of them, is that possible?

Comment: That's not a use case that AdMob supports. You can block individual categories of ads, but that's as granular as it gets.

Comment: you can programatically check how many ads shown up ,but not what ads are shown

Comment: Thank you guys.. what about ad review center. Does it cover most ads that bring revenue?